# Not parsing the datecolumn correctly

Tags: python

I am importing a csv into pandas dataframe. it does not import my date column correctly.
My CSV data

```
Ticker,Date_Time,Close,volume rate,Volatility,breakouthappened,prevdaycci negative,stopprice,day1gainpotential,day1closegainpotential,day2gainpotential,day3gainpotential,day4gainpotential,breakoutpoint,#
```

AAAP,12/27/2016,26.29,263,6.12,0,-165.77,23.51,-2.49,-4.95,-2.53,-2.71,0.51,24.39,1
ABMD,2/6/2017,110.5,261,3,1,-128.78,103.82,0.54,-1.15,-0.76,-1.6,-2,105.93,30
AIMC,4/11/2017,38.55,50,2.67,0,-20.65,37.6,-0.52,-2.46,-2.2,-3.37,-2.85,38.25,162

I do have a date in second column.

```
potential_trades_df=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\Ramesh\\PycharmProjects\\DemoTest\\TradeSignals.csv',parse_dates=True,keep_date_col = True)
currenttrade=potential_trades_df.iloc[0]


>>> currenttrade.Date_Time.strptime('%Y-%m-%d')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not too experienced with this. But I can give you something that helped me solve this issue.
You can write a parser method and convert strings into datetime object while reading it.

```
date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
parser = lambda x: pd .datetime.strptime(x, date_format)
```

And call it when you are reading it. (Assuming the column that has the dates is the index 0.

```
potential_trades_df=pd.read_csv('/path/to/file.csv',parse_dates=[0], date_parser=parser)
```

Doing that worked for me

EDIT: Also seems like the date format you wrote in your code is different than in your sample. In your sample the date_format is `"%m/%d/%Y"`

Comment: The date format in my sample is "%m/%d/%Y" but i need to parse it and then convert it to '%Y-%m-%d' as i have to query against mysql